# Reflection AccessControlException

Tags: java, security, exception, reflection, rmi

In my custom dataset, I'm using a constructor in the RMI Server to create a new instance of my class.

```
Constructor<?> constructor = dynTable.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.class);
constructor.setAccessible(true); // <-- Exception here
... = constructor.newInstance(type);
constructor.setAccessible(false);
```

However, if I set a `SecurityManager`, it throws the expection below.

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:457)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.setAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:128)
    at net.sviglas.meridian.task.DefaultDatasetConstructor$1.constructDataset(DefaultDatasetConstructor.java:45)
...
```

The policy file for both the server and the client:

```
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I gave permission for everything but I'm still getting this security exception. Do you know why?

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `setAccessible()` in a security context where it isn't permitted. You need to adjust your .policy file. Clearly your one with `allPermission` isn't being loaded. You need to execute your code with `-Djava.security.debug=access,failure` to see what security policy was in effect.

This has nothing to do with RMI, except that unless you're using the codebase feature you don't really need a security manager at all.

I'm also wondering why the constructor you're calling isn't already public.

Comment: I will use the codebase future so I need this. How can I be sure I\m using my policy file?

Comment: Also, the interesting thing is it works after first time. Server works fine on second try.

Comment: *I have told you* how to be sure about the security policy.